# Expo ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync Missing camera roll permission

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app, camera-roll

i am using `create-react-native-app` and i am having a problem with permissions in trying to get an image from the camera roll.

when i call the method: `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync`, i get the error: `Missing camera roll permission.`

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';

export const getImageFromLibrary = () => ({
    type: GET_IMAGE_FROM_LIBRARY,
    promise: () => ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px',
        base64: true
    })
});
```

the error: `Missing camera roll permission.` suggests that my app does not have permission, so i then created another button to request permission.

```
import { Permissions } from 'expo';

<Button
    onPress={() =>
        Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
            .then(console.log)
    }
><Text>get permission</Text></Button>
```

but when i click on this button i the `console.log()` method returns with: `{status: "granted", expires: "never"}`.

this would mean the permission is granted without ever expiring. but the call to get an image from the library is still denied for not having permission.

Comment: Try rolling back to version `24.0.3` if you have the latest. I think it is still an open issue in their library.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i changed the version of expo to and removed the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install`. unfortunately this does not work either. the command `Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)` now returns a promise containing `{status: "undetermined", expires: "never"}`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to ask for permission after downgrading. I have asked the Expo team regarding this: https://forums.expo.io/t/why-require-camera-roll-permission-for-imagepicker-in-v27/9744

Comment: this does not fix my issue. i have downgraded to expo version "24.0.3" as suggested. i then ran the command `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules && npm install && yarn cache clean`. but even after restarting Expo XDE and the iphone simulator, the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to expo version 27.0.1 and 28.0.0, then you should be able to see it working.

I tested it with CRNA project. It works fine.

Good luck!